# Specify location for the local perl library

Tags: macos, perl, ubuntu, locallib

Basically, I tried this on Ubuntu and OS X:

```
export PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT=~/.perl5
wget -O- http://cpanmin.us | perl - -l ~/.perl5 App::cpanminus local::lib
eval `perl -I ~/.perl5/lib/perl5 -Mlocal::lib`
```

Yet the third line insists on creating and installing all the stuff in `~/perl5` rather than `~/.perl5`. How can I overcome this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs,

> [If you installed local::lib into] a directory other than default, you also need to give that as import parameter to the call of the local::lib module like this way:
>
> ```
> echo 'eval "$(perl -I$HOME/foo/lib/perl5 -Mlocal::lib=$HOME/foo)"' >>~/.bashrc
> ```

So you need

```
echo 'eval "$(perl -I$HOME/.perl5/lib/perl5 -Mlocal::lib=$HOME/.perl5)"' >>~/.bashrc
```

Comment: I'm not a perl guy – I just wanted to hide perl dependencies from the users. This works, thank you.